# Error in Running Sql Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to execute this. It is giving me error for mysql syntax. Not able to figure out why.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO table2 (id,entity_type,`data`,processed,created_at,last_updated_at ) 
VALUES ( DEFAULT , 'campaigns', 
'{"campaign_id":"' CONCAT NEW.campaign_id CONCAT '","name":"' CONCAT NEW.name CONCAT '","advertiser_id":"' CONCAT NEW.advertiser_id CONCAT '","start_date":"' CONCAT NEW.start_date 
CONCAT '","end_date":"' CONCAT NEW.end_date CONCAT '","status":"' CONCAT NEW.status CONCAT '","pacing":"' CONCAT NEW.pacing CONCAT '","budget_value":"' CONCAT NEW.budget_value 
CONCAT '","gross_budget":"' CONCAT NEW.gross_budget CONCAT '"}' ,
0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ;
```

Comment: need to use with `delimiter $$` and `end $$` .. `delimiter ;` around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrongly used `CONCAT` in the statement.

It should be as shown in the statement below:

```
VALUES ( DEFAULT , 'campaigns',   
CONCAT( '{"campaign_id":"', NEW.campaign_id,
        '","name":"', NEW.name,
        '","advertiser_id":"', NEW.advertiser_id,
        '","start_date":"', NEW.start_date,
        '","end_date":"', NEW.end_date,
        '","status":"', NEW.status,
        '","pacing":"', NEW.pacing,
        '","budget_value":"', NEW.budget_value,
        '","gross_budget":"', NEW.gross_budget,
        '"}' ),  
0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ;
```

**Reference to Documentation**:

- [CONCAT(str1,str2,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

  - Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May
    have one or more arguments.

Comment: Also tell me one thing I am not able to use both insert and update at the same time. Any specific reason for that. Right now I used 'AFTER INSERT ON table1 '

Comment: `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are two different events. Their triggers are independent. You can't combine both of them as one *event*

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems on your trigger, I would start to fix it with something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1
AFTER INSERT ON table1 
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO table2 (entity_type,`data`,processed,created_at,last_updated_at) 
VALUES (
  'campaigns',
  CONCAT(
    '{',
    CONCAT_WS(
      ',',
      CONCAT('"campaign_id":"', NEW.campaign_id, '"'),
      CONCAT('"name":"', NEW.name, '"'),
      CONCAT('"status":"', NEW.status, '"'),
    ),
    '}'
  ),
  0,
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

CONCAT will concat the opening `{` with the values and the closing `}`.

All values will be calculated using CONCAT_WS that will create a comma separated string of values, and it will ignore null values.

This will make the trigger more readable.